# malloc в С, освобождение памяти под матрицу

Tags: c, память, выделение-памяти

Есть код. Со структурой matix_t которая хранит в себе значения матрицы и количество столбцов и строк. В функции create_matrix выполняется динамическое выделение памяти под эту структуры. Не могу разобрать эти строчки пошагово как они работают:

```
double **matrix =
    malloc(sizeof(double) * rows * columns + sizeof(double *) * rows);

for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    *(matrix + row) =
        (double *)((double **)((double *)matrix + row * columns) + rows);
```

Сама структура и функция целиком:

```
typedef struct matrix_struct {
    double** matrix;
    int rows;
    int columns;
} matrix_t;

int create_matrix(int rows, int columns, matrix_t *result){
  double **matrix =
    malloc(sizeof(double) * rows * columns/* + sizeof(double *) * rows*/);

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    *(matrix + row) =
        (double *)((double **)((double *)matrix + row * columns) + rows);

  result->matrix = matrix;
  result->rows = rows;
  result->columns = columns;

  initialize_matrix(result, 0.0);
}
```

В `initialize_matrix(result, 0.0)` происходит заполнение матрицы нулями.

Comment: Эти строчки плохо работают. Этот код под завязку набит неопределённым поведением. Не надо по нему учить C.

Comment: Это работает так: выделяется один блок памяти под список указателей на строки матрицы и под все числа в матрице. Затем в начало блока вписываются указатели на те места в этом же блоке где начинаются соответствующие строки матрицы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, как тогда лучше всего выделить память под матрицу?

Comment: Отдельно выделить массив указателей на строки. Отдельно - память под числа в матрице. Остальную логику можно сохранить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я вот еще не понимаю, зачем выделять память под список указателей на строки. Разве недостаточно выделить только для чисел в матрице?

Comment: Недостаточно, если вы хотите в дальнейшем использовать синтаксис `m[i][j]`. Что бы это работало `m` должен быть типа `double **` и указывать на массив `double *`. Каждый элемент этого массива (`m[i]`) указывает на строку.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо я разобрался)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, *"под завязку набит UB"* -- это о том, что он правилен только для 64-бит указателей? (учитывая IEE 754, другого размера double ожидать было бы странно)

Comment: @avp, размеры и выравнивание должны совпадать. Ещё я подозреваю что нельзя использовать адресную арифметику чтобы перескочить сегмент буфера с данными другого типа, даже если этот другой тип имеет тот же размер и выравнивание. То есть смешивать double и double * в одном буфере нельзя.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, что вы называете буфером? Насколько я помню, в языке нет такого понятия. Массивов (про которые компилятор знает) тут тоже нет. Вообще, для переносимости, тут достаточно добавить padding после памяти под указатели, чтобы double были гарантировано выравнены на 8

Comment: @avp, буфером я назвал результат работы `malloc`.  На любой разумной архитектуре выровнен так что технически padding не нужен. Я подозреваю что UB в данном случае - смешение адресных арифметик в общей памяти. Даже если параметры адресных арифметик одинаковы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я имел в виду padding между массивом указателей на строки матрицы (в 32-bit архитектуре при нечетном числе строк адрес начала данных окажется кратен 4-м, но не 8-ми). Про проблемы с каким-либо  смешением никогда не слышал и не представляю, откуда им взяться. Если вы про *strict-aliasing*, то это другое